# folium choropleth not showing when called

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

my folium choropleth is not showing when I call it or display it. I am working in Chrome. It only shows when it has no data and after data has been added to it.

When I customized the graph so that it shows details and highlight when I hover to it, it doesn't show the map at all when it is being called.

I have two dataset imported. One is postcode and price (in csv), another one is postcode, geometry and area (in shapefile). Everything works well except after I apply .add_child(NIL) where it doesn't show the map at all

```
    mymap = folium.Map(location=[y_map, x_map], zoom_start=11,tiles=None)
folium.TileLayer('CartoDB positron',name="Light Map",control=False).add_to(mymap)
mymap

myscale = (merged['Price'].quantile((0,0.1,0.75,0.9,0.98,1))).tolist()
mymap.choropleth(
 geo_data=merged,
 name='Choropleth',
 data=merged,
 columns=['Postcode','Price'],
 key_on="feature.properties.Postcode",
 fill_color='YlGnBu',
 threshold_scale=myscale,
 fill_opacity=1,
 line_opacity=0.2,
 legend_name='Prices of property Australia',
 smooth_factor=0,
    highlight=True
)

mymap #map only shows when it is called here, it won't show up after the following code is added and run



NIL = folium.features.GeoJson(
    merged,
    style_function=style_function, 
    control=False,
    highlight_function=highlight_function, 
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['Postcode','Price'],
        aliases=['Postcode: ','Price: '],
        style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
    )
)


mymap.add_child(NIL)
mymap.keep_in_front(NIL)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(mymap)
mymap
```

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RBeW.png)

Comment: avoid adding code as an image, instead, use code brackets (```) and copy and paste the code

Comment: What is the essence of your question? That you can't see the map? The highlight is that you will see? Remove it if that's not what you want.

Comment: I can only see the map before I customise it. When I added "NIL" to the map, it won't show up

Answer (score 0):

Because the code and data are unknown, the following example was created using a partial example from the forum site to create an example style function and highlighting function. When you run this code, the states are demarcated in blue, and highlighted with the mouse, they are demarcated in red.
If you want to make it into a function, the example is in the form of def().

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data'
us_states = f'{url}/us-states.json'

geo_json_data = json.loads(requests.get(us_states).text)

m = folium.Map([43, -100], zoom_start=4)

def style_function(feature):
    return {
        'fillColor': '#ffaf00',
        'color': 'blue',
        'weight': 1.5,
        'dashArray': '5, 5'
    }

def highlight_function(feature):
    return {
        'fillColor': '#ffaf00',
        'color': 'red',
        'weight': 3,
        'dashArray': '5, 5'
    }

folium.GeoJson(
    geo_json_data,
    style_function=style_function,
    highlight_function=highlight_function
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i forgot to say that my data are actually not unknown, i didn't include the very beginning of this code where I got everything okay up to showing the map with color in it (see my updated screenshot). my map won't show up after i apply the do .add_child(NIL)